# 2 part dynamic select

Tags: vba, excel

I received a lot of help on this initially, but I've come to another bump in the road. The code below copies everything I need but pastes it wrong. 
I need the following code to work BUT I want to add to it that **I only want column K to paste values.** The other columns have formatting I need.  Any ideas??

```
Sub getScheduleCurrentMonth()
Dim celltxt As String
Dim N As Long
Dim r As Integer

'get the current month orders

With Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim foundIt As Range
    Set foundIt = .Range("B1:B1000").Find("CURRENT MONTH", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not foundIt Is Nothing Then

    Set foundIt = .Range(foundIt.Offset(1, -1), foundIt.End(xlDown)) 'from column A and down
    Set foundIt = foundIt.Resize(foundIt.rows.Count, 30) 'from column A to AD
    foundIt.Copy

    Workbooks("AutomationTest.xlsm").Worksheets("Fast Track").Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 'xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Else
        MsgBox ("No data for Current Month Found")

    End If

End With
```

Comment: *"I only want column K to paste values"* I'm not sure what you mean by this. You want your data pasted into column K???

Comment: @dwirony no I want everything to paste regular but I want values from column K to paste special because it's tied to a formula.

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid using `.Copy` / `.Paste` whenever possible.

See if the following works for you:

```
Sub getScheduleCurrentMonth()

    Dim celltxt As String, N As Long, r As Long
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsTgt As Worksheet
    Set wsSrc = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTgt = Workbooks("AutomationTest.xlsm").Worksheets("Fast Track")

    'get the current month orders
    Dim foundIt As Range, copyRng As Range, pasteRng As Range

    With wsTgt
        r = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    Set foundIt = wsSrc.Range("B1:B1000").Find("CURRENT MONTH", LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not foundIt Is Nothing Then

        Set copyRng = wsSrc.Range("A" & foundIt.Row, "AD" & foundIt.Row)
        Set pasteRng = wsTgt.Range("A" & r, "AD" & r)
        pasteRng.Value = copyRng.Value

    Else

        MsgBox ("No data for Current Month Found")

    End If


End Sub

tion.ScreenUpdating = True

    Else

        MsgBox ("No data for Current Month Found")

    End If


End Sub
```